# Why does my app not fill the entire screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

Here I have 2 screenshots

[image]

[image]

The top one is my app. The 2nd one is facebook. Notice how facebook takes up the entire screen while mine is just short of reaching the top and bottom. How can I get my app to fill the entire screen, or atleast have it extend to right under the time and battery percentage?

Styles XML file

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorBlack</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="navigationViewStyle">@style/Widget.Design.NavigationView</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

Layout XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnApply"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@color/colorPrimary" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtApplyButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="APPLY"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:fontFamily="@font/varela"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btnApply"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btnApply"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btnApply"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnApply" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtFirstName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/first_name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:maxLength="30"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtLastName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/last_name"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:maxLength="30"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLocation"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Locations"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGray"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtLocation">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btnAddLocation"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btnRemoveLocation"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spnrLocations"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="50" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgVerified"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtVerified"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/varela"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGreen"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgVerified"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".EmailSignUp" />
    <activity android:name=".EmailVerification" />
    <activity android:name=".EmailSignIn" />
    <activity android:name=".Home" />
    <activity android:name=".AddLocation" />
    <activity android:name=".InstantMessage" />
    <activity android:name=".ProcessPayment" />

    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

Comment: Can you add code related to the First screenshot

Comment: @Garren,  Can you send activity's java, layout.xml, and AnroidManifest? Are you want to make slimmer the black status bar?

Comment: I can start a new project and run it on my phone and it looks fine, so i mustve change something in the layout file, just dont know what it is. I edited my post to show layout xml file.

Comment: can you show your manifest ?

Comment: @AshwiniViolet I added manifest. I have tried replacing all project files with the default ones from the new project wizard, and it still displays incorrectly, yet when I run a new project wizard and it creates the same exact files I had in my project, it runs just fine. So the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Once i also had this kind situation... My all material effect were gone.... Then I found that i enabled hardware acceleration in my manifest...

Comment: But Your manifest is okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I woke up this morning, tried running it again, and everything looked fine. I changed absolutely nothing. Android studio/my phone must have a mind of it's own.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one theme

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: it still refuses the stretch across the entire screen vertically

Comment: Posted edited. The problem happens throughout all activities of the app. The size is consistent no matter which layout is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this programmatically

You need to set up

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flag);
```

Setup these flags inside onWindowFocusChanged of your activity (onWindowFocusChanged 
 mainly used for fullscreen so you can retain your fullscreen even after focus change. you can also set flags in your onCreate or where you like)

in your activity you can do like

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

   //You can also pass multiple flags as i did. one for hide navigation one for make layout stable
   getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                       |View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);


                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For Extra there is also other flags that change system ui like flag for fullscreen.

[here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View) you can find all flags. just search for system_ui_flag